# Как перевести цвет фона сайта в градации серого (grayscale)?

Tags: css, wordpress

[image: Как перевести цвет фона сайта в градации серого (grayscale)]

Сайту задан фоновый цвет через `Customizer`.

Нужно перевести весь сайт в градации серого.

Применяю к `body` свойство `filter: grayscale(1);`.
Но, если задан цвет фону, то он не меняется.

Подскажите, как перевести в градации серого всё содержимое сайта, включая заданный через `Customizer` цвет фона?

Comment: А где уверенность в том, что цвет фона задается именно в body? Покажите ваш код. Кроме того, учтите, что `filter: grayscale(1);` не работает в IE.

Comment: В вопрос добавлена картинка: слева — то, что настроено в `Customizer`, справа — стили для  `body` в инспекторе.

Comment: Должно работать. Возможно, где-то выше наложен блок с таким же background. Правой кнопкой в нужной точке - просмотреть код - **Computed** - background-color и клик по стрелочке в черном кружочке, чтобы увидеть, где и как задан стиль: http://take.ms/BXgRk

Comment: И да - а класс grayscale-mode присвоен элементу, у которого надо поменять фон?

Comment: `<body class="home blog logged-in admin-bar custom-background wp-custom-logo grayscale-mode customize-support" style>`. Фильтр влияет на картинки, фон у элементов на странице, но не влияет на фон сайта.

Comment: Значит, фон сайта задан в другом элементе. Вы смотрели computed, как я написал?

Comment: @KAGG Design, да, в Computed для `body` задан `background-color` в `(index)`, а также `filter` в `style.css`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69340/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-eav).